# Replace a value in array after sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I sort my json data in the correct order, however I would like to replace the value of the position.

My json data :

```
    {
      "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 1,
        "points": 35
      },
      "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 2,
        "points": 38
      },
      "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 3,
        "points": 37
      }
    }
```

What I want :

```
    {
      "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 1,
        "points": 38
      },
      "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 2,
        "points": 37
      },
      "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
        "id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 3,
        "points": 35
      }
    }
```

My code :

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('course.json/rank.json', 'utf8');
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    const comparePoints = (a,b)=>{

      let a_points = a["points"]
      let b_points = b["points"]

      return b_points-a_points
    }

    const sort = (data) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(data)
    let dataAsArray = keys.map(e=>data[e])
    return dataAsArray.sort(comparePoints)
    }

    data = sort(data);
    console.log(data);
```

What I get:

```
    [ { "id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 2,
        "points": 38 },
      { "id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 3,
        "points": 37 },
      { "id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
        "user_id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr",
        "myposition": 1,
        "points": 35 } ]
```

I would like to swap the positions, can you help me? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically with your code you an `Array` not another object, so you need to recreate the object from your sorted array.
That can be done using reduce for each or any looping function. I think reduce is the more easy to see.

here you have using `what you get` and returning `what you want`

```js
const yourResult = [
  {
    "id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 2,
    "points": 38
  },
  {
    "id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 3,
    "points": 37
  },
  {
    "id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 1,
    "points": 35
  }
]

const whatYouWant = yourResult.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  c['myposition'] = i + 1;
  a[c.id] = c;
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(whatYouWant)
```

Answer (score 2):

use [object values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to extract the values of the object , [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort) them then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to rebuild the object:

```js
const json = {
  "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
    "id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "dev@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 2,
    "points": 35
  },
  "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
    "id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "fbl@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 1,
    "points": 38
  },
  "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10": {
    "id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr-Quiz-10",
    "user_id": "ddd@be-activ-it.fr",
    "myposition": 3,
    "points": 37
  }
};

const result = Object.values(json).sort((a, b) => a.myposition - b.myposition).reduce((all, curr) => {
  all[curr.id] = curr;
  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const comparePoints = (a,b)=>{

  let a_points = a["points"]
  let b_points = b["points"]

  return a_points-b_points
}
```

Instead b-a try a-b. Visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort